# select item with beautifulsoup

Tags: html, css, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I have the following list of results:

```
<div id="resultlist" class="result-list ">
   <article itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Residence" class="search-result-entry  ">
   <article itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Residence" class="search-result-entry  ">
   <article class="search-result-entry" id="wh_adition_FakeAd1">
   <article itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Residence" class="search-result-entry  ">
...
```

With beautifulsoup I try to select all entries with the class "search-result-entry", and the itemtype="http://schema.org/Residence".

```
response = requests.get(url)

#cancel parsing if page doesnt exists
if response.status_code is not 200:
    return

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
#print(soup.select("resultlist")

#select all listings from lise, execlude adds
results = soup.select('.search-result-entry')
print(results)
```

However, at the moment I'm selecting also those with the `id="wh_adition_FakeAd1"`, which gives me an index error some lines later.
I tried this, without any result:

```
results = soup.select('.search-result-entry meta[itemtype=http://schema.org/Residence]')
```

Any idea how I can manage to select only the entries, that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Find all article tags that have your desired itemtype. This will print only the ones with that attribute.

```
for line in soup.findAll("article", {"itemtype" : "http://schema.org/Residence"}):
    print line
```

And you can do the same with the ones that have and ID

```
for line in soup.findAll("article", {"id" : "wh_adition_FakeAd1"}):
    print line
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem. Glad it was helpful.